# Determine if a date is within 2 dates in sqlCE

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce

I have an sqlCE field A, type text, that holds a date string in this format:

```
31/12/2011 11:29:09
```

Also, I have an sqlCE field B, type text, that holds a date string in this format:

```
04/04/2011 10:12:01
```

Today's date in my computer is :`19/01/09 21:54:28`

How can I check if today's date is between date A and date B, with any region or date type?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your database field is of type `text`, then you first need to *parse* the text value into a (genuine) datetime value. The recommended function for this is `DateTime.ParseExact`. Example:

```
string myString = ...; // the value you read from the database
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(myString, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
                                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

About the "*with any region or date type*" you mentioned in the question: That's what the second and third parameter of ParseExact is about: There, you can specify the format that the text values in the database have. (See [the documentation of DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) for more details.) Note that you *do* need to specify the format: Otherwise, the function wouldn't be able to tell whether `03/04/2010` is the fourth of March or the third of April.

Afterwards, you can use regular date comparison operations (e.g. `if (datetime1 <= datetime2) { ... }`) to check if the date is within the desired time frame.